# Pair Android Bluetooth without passkey to PC

Tags: android, windows, linux, bluetooth, communication

my issue is that I have a PC host to manage Bluetooth connections in a wide room, e.g. a shopping center. And I want that any customer who wants to pair to that host, which provides a service, do it automatically without asking for a passkey by the PC, since this will not be managed by anyone.

My real application is a platform which manages this kind of connection and I want to pair BT devices to it, but not asking for any passkey at least from PC side.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**go to your bluetooth settings and disable the security option and if you find the authentication on connect something like that option juss uncheck it and try again**

Comment: But on Windows there is no any option to allow automatic pairing, in any case you have to confirm in the PC the connection, and I want just to search the PC Bluetooth from my Android phone and just connect, without passkey, confirmation, etc...

Comment: then go to your device paired device list and when you found your pc name in it juss make it "authenticate device" so in future it will not show you a passkey dialogue when you connect it with system